# JAXB marshalling and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, jaxb

I have 2 classes, one extends the other. The superclass marshals correctly, but the subclass, which adds one attribute, does not. The extra attribute is not present in the XML.

Superclass:

```
@XmlRootElement()
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class SessionRecord extends Record {

  SimpleDateFormat hhmm = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
  SimpleDateFormat day = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE");

  @XmlAttribute protected int sessionId;
  @XmlAttribute protected boolean open;
  @XmlAttribute protected boolean night;
  protected Date start;
  protected Date finish;
  protected boolean setup;
  protected boolean takedown;

  @XmlAttribute
  public String getDescription() {
        if (start==null) start = new Date();
        if (finish==null) finish = new Date();
        return day.format(start)+(night ? " Night " : " ")+hhmm.format(start)+"-"+hhmm.format(finish)+" "+type();
  }

  private String type() {
        return setup ? "Setup" : (open ? "Open" : (takedown ? "Takedown" : ""));
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public boolean isSetupTakedown() {
        return setup || takedown;
  }
```

}

This produces XML elements similar to this:

```
<sessionRecord setupTakedown="true" description="Saturday 09:00-13:00 Setup" night="false" open="false" sessionId="0"/>
```

which is OK.

But the subclass:

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class VolunteerSession extends SessionRecord {

  @XmlAttribute private boolean available;

}
```

Produces identical output, the `available` attribute is not marshalled. Why is JAXB not marshalling the extra attribute?

EDIT

further information:

Record superclass is merely this:

```
public abstract class Record {}
```

Here is the class representing the top-level document element. It contains lists of Records:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="response")
@XmlSeeAlso({
  RecordList.class, 
  VolunteerAssignment.class, 
  VolunteerRecord.class,
  SessionRecord.class,
  VolunteerSession.class,
  VolunteerArea.class,
  PossibleAssignment.class})
public class XMLResponse {

  @XmlAttribute private String errorMessage;

  private List<RecordList<? extends Record>> recordLists  = new ArrayList<RecordList<? extends Record>>();

  //snip...

  public void setError(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
  }

  @XmlMixed
  public List<RecordList<? extends Record>> getRecordLists() {
        return recordLists;
  }

}
```

and finally, RecordList

```
@XmlRootElement()
public class RecordList<T extends Record> {

  @XmlAttribute private String name;
  @XmlAttribute private int total;
  @XmlAttribute private int count;
  @XmlAttribute private int start;
  @XmlAttribute private boolean update;
  private List<T> records;

  // snip constructors, setters

  @XmlMixed
  public List<T> getRecords() {
        return records;
  }

}
```

Comment: Try adding the avaialble getter and setters in your VolunteerSession class.

Comment: Tried that, no difference

Comment: Can you add your `Record` class and how you create your `JAXBContext`?

Comment: extra info added as requested. Actually the @XmlSeeAlso is in XMLResponse, not Record as I previously said, but that shouldn't make much dirrerence

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though the `VolunteerSession` class is not being included in the `JAXBContext`.  This can happen depending on how you created your `JAXBContext`.  Below is some example code where the same object is marshalled based on 3 different instances of `JAXBContext` each bootstrapped off a different class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        VolunteerSession volunteerSession = new VolunteerSession();

        marshal(VolunteerSession.class, volunteerSession);
        marshal(SessionRecord.class, volunteerSession);
        marshal(XMLResponse.class, volunteerSession);
    }

    private static void marshal(Class bootstrapClass, Object object) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(bootstrapClass.getName());
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(bootstrapClass);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(object, System.out);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**Output**

1. When the `JAXBContext` is bootstrapped off of `VolunteerSession` obviously it has the necessary information.
2. When the `JAXBContext` is bootstraped off of the super class `SessionRecord` it doesn't pull in `VolunteerSession`.  JAXB will automatically process metadata for super classes, but not subclasses. `@XmlSeeAlso` is usually used in this case to reference mapped subclasses.
3. `VolunteerRecord` contains an `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation that references `VolunteerSession`.  Therefore `VolunteerSession` is processed as part of the `JAXBContext` and contains the necessary information when marshalled.

```xml
forum20908213.VolunteerSession
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<volunteerSession available="false" sessionId="0" open="false" night="false" description="Sunday 05:53-05:53 " setupTakedown="false"/>

forum20908213.SessionRecord
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<sessionRecord sessionId="0" open="false" night="false" description="Sunday 05:53-05:53 " setupTakedown="false"/>

forum20908213.XMLResponse
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<volunteerSession available="false" sessionId="0" open="false" night="false" description="Sunday 05:53-05:53 " setupTakedown="false"/>
```

Comment: +1 This is interesting. I don't think I can access the marshalling code itself, as it's all done for me by Spring MVC.

Comment: @NickJ - I think the solution to your problem will be to add an `@XmlSeeAlso` with a reference `VolunteerSession` to `Record` or `SessionRecord`.  One thing I was trying to point out with my answer is that based on how the `JAXBContext` is created different metadata can be created.

Answer (score 1):

You have to list all of your subclasses in [@XmlSeeAlso](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) annotation of your parent class.

Comment: In fact, I have already done that. Sorry, should have made it clear. It's in the `Record` superclass above `SessionRecord`

Comment: +1 - You can also pass them in as the list of classes used to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.

Comment: extra info added as requested. Actually the @XmlSeeAlso is in XMLResponse, not Record as I previously said, but that shouldn't make much dirrerence

Comment: working sort-of OK now. Don't know what I did, but the XML representation of a SessionRecord also includes the available attribute, for some strange reason. That doesn't matter though.